# Where is the method of Contour integration used in physics?

Tags: soft-question, complex-numbers, analyticity, big-list

Complex numbers have a wide variety of application in physics and so must be contour integration but where do we exactly apply the principles of contour integration, residues and poles in the field of physics?

Comment: landau damping is a good example

Comment: This is a big-list question, and the policy about big-list questions is that they will get closed.

Comment: You may encounter real integrals with limits of integration that are infinite. You can use residues from the Cauchy residue theorem to solve these integrals under certain conditions.

Comment: @Ali I need few examples from your big list.